# How to calculate age with JPA 2 criteria queries?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm quite amazed that I could not find anything on this topic:

> How do I calculate the age of a person at a given date, based on a
>   date of birth and using only regular JPA criteria queries?

There are plenty of native SQL solutions, but I could not find a simple and elegant vendor-agnostic criteria.

Cheers!

Comment: I've not investigated the problem very much, but in most situations, that can be circumvented by just getting the date of birth from the database and compute the age in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no arithmetic operations for date operands in JPA 2.0. Also three existing date related functions in JP QL (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and corresponding methods in Criteria API (*currentDate(), currentTime(), currentTimestamp()*) have nothing to do with calculations. That makes it impossible to perform calculations with dates. Just calculate in Java, as JB Nizet said.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To clarify, I'm trying to create ad-hoc statistics from the database. Aggregations and group-bys and so on: What's the age distribution of 10k+ people? Doing this in Java would, of course, be possible and easy, but not very fast I'm afraid.

Comment: You could use the CriteriaBuilder.function method (if a suitable database function exists), but it would of course not be database agnostic.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but as you said, it will only work in a single database. Thanks for the answer though, although it is a bit disappointing. :-(